# Google Earth Engine: undefined value conversion

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using the Google Earth Engine API in Python. I am trying to reconvert undefined (i.e. null) values onto a value of choice. Inspired by a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237278/google-earthengine-getting-time-series-for-reduceregion/42788765#42788765), my code is as follows:

```py
import ee

ee.Initialize()
c = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').filterDate('2003-12-19', '2004-01-19').select('NDVI')
p = ee.Geometry.Point([-8.802372,  41.722677])
data = c.getRegion(p, scale = 1000).getInfo()
print 'data=',data

def filterNull(img):
    ndviU = img.select('NDVI')
    ndviF = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(ndviU, None), -2000, ndviU)
    return img.addBands(ndviF) 

cf = c.map(filterNull)
dataf = cf.getRegion(p, scale = 1000).getInfo()
print 'dataf=',dataf
```

It doesn't work though, the output indicates no change for the None value.

```py
data= [[u'id', u'longitude', u'latitude', u'time', u'NDVI'], 
       [u'2003_12_19', -8.798998207950714, 41.72225337093118, 1071792000000L, None], 
       [u'2004_01_01', -8.798998207950714, 41.72225337093118, 1072915200000L, 7339], 
       [u'2004_01_17', -8.798998207950714, 41.72225337093118, 1074297600000L, 7090]]
dataf= [[u'id', u'longitude', u'latitude', u'time', u'NDVI', u'NDVI_1'], 
        [u'2003_12_19', -8.798998207950714, 41.72225337093118, 1071792000000L, None, None], 
        [u'2004_01_01', -8.798998207950714, 41.72225337093118, 1072915200000L, 7339, 7339], 
        [u'2004_01_17', -8.798998207950714, 41.72225337093118, 1074297600000L, 7090, 7090]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [ee.Image.unmask()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageunmask) is used to convert an image's masked values to actual values. To apply to all images in a collection, use [ee.ImageCollection.map()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectionmap) to map a function that operates on a single image.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, I was able to solve the problem by using `unmask` as follows:

```
def filterNull(img):
    return img.addBands(img.select('NDVI').unmask(-2000))
cf = c.map(filterNull)
```

Is this the most appropriate mechanism?